# How do I make a gradient color background fill in GIMP?

Tags: images, gimp, gradient

I need to make a small image with a gradient color background.  How can I do that in GIMP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [blend tool (L)](http://manual.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-blend.html).

Comment: Right next to the paint bucket tool that I was *trying* to use. :)  Thanks.